# PasswordBox Visual States are missing?

Tags: .net, wpf, c#-4.0

I am trying to set the visual state of a `PasswordBox` to indicate an error if the password is incorrect.

According to the MSDN documentation [PasswordBox Syles and Templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff468216%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) (spelling error theirs), the following visual states are defined in the following visual state groups:

- Normal - CommonStates
- MouseOver - CommonStates
- Disabled - CommonStates
- Focused - FocusStates
- Unfocused - FocusStates
- Valid - ValidationStates
- InvalidFocused - ValidationStates
- InvalidUnfocused - ValidationStates

The following code, however, always returns an empty list:

```
public void Blah(PasswordBox passwordBox)
{
     var visualStateGroups = VisualStateManager.GetVisualStateGroups(passwordBox);
     //visualStates.Count is always 0.
}
```

And trying to go to a state always returns false, e.g.

```
public void Halb(PasswordBox passwordBox)
{
   bool didTransition = VisualStateManager.GoToState(passwordBox, 
                                                    "InvalidFocused", 
                                                     true);

   //didTransition is always false. It doesn't make a difference whether
   //or not the last paramter is "true" or "false"
}
```

Why are the documented VisualStates/VisualStateGroups documented on msdn apparently missing in code?  Am I doing something wrong (my suspicion), or is MSDN incorrect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first part of your question's answer is in MSDN [VisualStateManager.GetVisualStateGroups](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc838810%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) comments

> "VisualStateGroups are usually set on the root of an element's visual tree, not on the element itself."

so

```
public void Blah(PasswordBox passwordBox)
{
    var bd = pbox.Template.FindName("Bd", pbox) as FrameworkElement;
    var visualStateGroups = VisualStateManager.GetVisualStateGroups(bd);
    Debug.WriteLine(visualStateGroups.Count);
    // should print 3
}
```

As for the second part, that works fine for me,

if I define the VSG's such as

```
<VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
  <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates" />
  <VisualStateGroup x:Name="FocusStates" />
  <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ValidationStates">
    <VisualState x:Name="Valid" />
    <VisualState x:Name="InvalidFocused">
      <Storyboard>
        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="PART_ContentHost"
                                      Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)">
          <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                Value="#FF9B4A4A" />
        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
      </Storyboard>
    </VisualState>
    <VisualState x:Name="InvalidUnfocused" />
  </VisualStateGroup>
</VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
```

Now `VisualStateManager.GoToState(passwordBox, "InvalidFocused", true);` returns `true` and I can see the control styled accordingly.

**Update:**

AFAIK think it's just in Silverlight that `VisualState`'s are automatically defined for `PasswordBox`. In WPF you'd have to define them yourself. Expression blend does slightly help by giving you the states in the `States` tab of the IDE and when you're recording changes, it will auto-generate code for accompanying `Storyboard`'s, but not without you editing the `Template` that is.

[As stated here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/expression/en-US/3d11add2-0559-4b4f-a9d5-8934e24ff2b7/states-panel-empty) guess that's just because default Style's in WPF do not use the VSM out-of-the-box.

[Download link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/s6pd0i3nicholez/WpfApplication31.rar) to a sample where "we" explicitly define VSM and `VisualState`'s for a `PasswordBox` with both the previous functions I posted originally shown working.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Your first example gives ``null`` for ``bd`` (and I tried replacing ``"Bd"`` with ``"passwordBox"``, which since my xaml is ``<PasswordBox x:Name="passwordBox" ...`` with the same result.)  As for the second,  I may be missing something fundamental here, but shouldn't the VisualStates already be defined?  Why should I have to redefine them in Xaml?

Comment: Not sure if it's relevant, but ``passwordBox.Template.VisualTree`` is also ``null``, which is not what I expected to find.

Comment: @Nathan I've updated my answer and also included a sample download you can try to show the functions working, however do think you would have to define the `VisualState`'s in WPF since they do not use VSM by default for their state's unlike silverlight.

Comment: Your example works, and I now see that ``"Bd"`` is the control you defined in your style template.  However, one interesting tidbit is, that if I rename all occurrences of ``InvalidFocused`` to anything else, your example still works.  So it appears that we are defining the visual states in their entirety - which leads me to wonder why the http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff468216%28v=vs.100%29.aspx even exists, since the documented states don't appear to be of any consequence, and the page says nothing about Silverlight. At any rate, this allows me to move forward.

Comment: @Nathan It's not of much use indeed. Only probably as a hint of the different possible states a control normally has. As for the documentation, the link i posted in my answer has the reply `Thanks for pointing out that the help topic does not make that clear ... Again, thanks for pointing out the doc issue. I also encourage you to send feedback about the docs for such issues. (There is a feedback link for each topic at the bottom of each page)` Guess they still haven't got around to it.